# Crosstab query column headings in MS Access based on a grouping of the data variables in a column of a table

Tags: sql, ms-access, crosstab

I am designing a crosstab query in MS Access.

I would like to use the first 2 digits of an ID number as column headings for my query. For example, the ID's `0123` and `0124` would all be under the same column with the heading `group 01`, whereas the IDs `0234` and `0235` would fall under a `group 02` column.

These ID numbers exist in the table I am building my crosstab query from. I have currently selected `ID number` as my column headings, but that results in getting `0123`, `0124`, etc, creating hundreds of columns when I really just want a few columns- one for each group.
There is a delimiter between the first few digits and the rest of the identifier.

How can I get the column headings I want? I am thinking perhaps using a wildcard character after my delimiter would be helpful.

Comment: Can you create/add column that would hold only first 2 digits of ID and use that as column headings? I am not very familiar with MS Access, so please pardon me if this does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and save a new query, where you build the values you want to pivot on:

```
SELECT 'group ' & Left([ID], 2) AS PivotColumn, foo, bar
FROM myTable
```

Then, e.g. using the crosstab query wizard, create your crosstab query based on this query instead of the original table.